# How to define conjunction in terms of a conditional and biconditional?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

I need help with defining conjunction while only using a conditional (implication) and a biconditional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $A \land B$ as $A \leftrightarrow (A \rightarrow B)$

We could make truth table assignment to check that the definition is valid.

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
A & B & (A \rightarrow B) & A \leftrightarrow (A \rightarrow B)\\\hline
T & T & T & T\\
T & F & F & F\\
F & T & T & F\\
F & F & T & F\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. How would you define conditional in terms of a biconditional and a conjunction then?

Comment: $(A \land B) \leftrightarrow A$ may be an answer for $A \rightarrow B$

Comment: Yes.  $A\to B$ is true when $A$ is false or $A$ and $B$ are both true. $A\to B$ is false when $A$ is true but $B$ false (so $A\wedge B$ is false.)